# How to change pdf to make it open full screen?

Tags: pdf

I have some scripts that auto-generate pdf files (some use ImageMagick `convert`). They are meant to be viewed full screen ('presentation mode'), which is easy to do manually with some visualization programs (Okular for instance, but I was unable to do that on a Mac yesterday).

Since pdf have an internal option to open full screen (OpenAction), I'd like to set it, either at creation time with `convert`, or with an additional command. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: You cannot enforce fullscreen, certainly not on a Mac. It is entirely at the user's discretion.

Comment: To be fair I couldn't even figure out how to full screen manually on a Mac... I'll keep my opinion of that system to myself.

Comment: Green dot, top left. Didn't look far… & I'll keep my opinion of Windows to myself too. Fair exchange.

Comment: I don't have a Mac in front of me now, but that's just maximized, not full-screen, right ?

Comment: No, you can maximise by alt/clicking the green dot, just clicking uses true fullscreen, in its own Space. Many [but not all] apps can use Cmd/Ctrl/F too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and remember that for next time (and BTW my opinion of Windows is probably the same as yours...)